# How to save data in Json format and send it to server via API?

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanted to  save all the form data in Json format and send it from my UI to the server.

I tried with all the sources available.

I am stuck in the basic design structure. It would be most appreciated if anyone could assist.

Comment: you have create an injectable service class to add the method which saves the data over http call

Comment: you can refer this article https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 this is very basic requirement so you will find solution just by google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple way:

1. Add a reference to ngForm to your form element : `<form #f="ngForm">`
2. Add a name attribute to all your inputs. This will be the keys in your json. While you're at it, add a reference to ngModel on each one too : `<input ngModel name="fname" type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">`
3. Get a reference of your form in the compoment using ViewChild : `@ViewChild("f") form: NgForm;`
4. Inject an HttpClient in your component : `constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}`
5. Use it to post your data to the server: `this.httpClient.post('http:///some/url',this.form.value).subscribe();`

Here is an exampe based on your code sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdcwps

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: If this solvers your problem, can you please accept the answer (white check mark below the up/down-vote buttons) to indicate this question is answered. Thanks